# Experimental Design resources request

Tags: references, experiment-design

I am working my way through the book [Experimental Design by Berger, Maurer and Celli](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319645827) and was wondering if there are supplementary materials (such as video lectures) which are easier to digest. The chapters I am mainly focusing on are 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11 and 16. Thanks in advance for any resources!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Gary Oehlert's free book, located here:
[http://users.stat.umn.edu/~gary/Book.html](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Egary/Book.html)
Another author's insight might be just what you need.
Good luck!